# $.when - done gets called before all promises are resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, promise, jquery-deferred

Here's my code to fetch some backbone collections concurrently:

```
$.when.apply(this, _.map(collection_params_pairs, function(pair) {
     pair.collection.fetch({
          data: pair.params,
          success: function(collection, response) {
            console.log('success');
          }
     });
})).done(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

When I run it, `done` gets logged to the console before `success`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your `_.map` return? I see that it returns an array of `undefined`, so nothing to wait for for `when`.

Comment: argh, hard to focus on Friday evening. Thanks!

Comment: Nobody seems to be telling you what you need to actually change.  Inside your `.map()` callback, you NEED to be returning a promise that `$.when()` can then operate on.  As it is now, you're not passing any promises to `$.when()` so it has nothing to wait for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_.map()` call in your code returns an array of `undefined`, so `$.when()` does not have any promises to wait for.

Hence it resolves immediately.

Answer (score 4):

`$.when()` needs a set of promises so it can monitor those promises and trigger your `.done()` handler when all those promises are themselves finished.  The way your code is structured with the return results from `_.map()` being sent to `$.when()`, you need to return a promise from the `.map()` callback function.

So ... assuming that `pair.collection.fetch()` already returns a promise (it looks like it returns a jqXHR object which is a promise), you can do this:

```
$.when.apply($, _.map(collection_params_pairs, function(pair) {
     return pair.collection.fetch({
          data: pair.params,
          success: function(collection, response) {
            console.log('success');
          }
     });
})).done(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

If `pair.collection.fetch()` doesn't return a promise, then you need to create one in order to use `$.when()`:

```
$.when.apply($, _.map(collection_params_pairs, function(pair) {
     var def = $.Deferred();
     pair.collection.fetch({
          data: pair.params,
          success: function(collection, response) {
            def.resolve(response);
            console.log('success');
          }
     });
     return def.promise();
})).done(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

FYI, you should probably also be handling errors on your `pair.collection.fetch()` call as I assume it has an error path of some type.

Comment: Backbone's `collection.fetch` returns a jqXHR object which is a promise - so the second bunch of logic (creating a deferred) isn't really needed.

Comment: Just a minor note: "needs an array of promises" --- it needs N arguments (variadics?)